# Display/Hide DIVs on tablecell hover (javascript)

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I built a table with about 20 cells. Next to the table I want to display a `<div>` with a description, which should be displayed on hover or on click.  There are heaps of solutions available on the web, but none really fits.

I already know I do need JavaScript, so i have my table cell

```
<td class="des1">Content</td>
```

and

```
<div id="des1">my Description1</div>
```

*I add a class to the cells because some descriptions are called by more than one cell.*

So, I need a JavaScript function to show the div "des1" on hover/click of all cells of class "des1", and also hide all other descriptions shown before. And that is my problem.

All my descriptions are wrapped in on other div so can I hide all divs in the wrapper and then display the right description.  What is the best way to do this (event handling? inline?) Should I use CSS in Addition?

I do not have much experience in Javascript so I would appreciate any help or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic parts to what you are trying to achieve:

1. event handling (to do things in response to the user hovering/clicking)
2. DOM manipulation (to change the description).

I would strongly advise using the [jQuery library](http://www.jquery.com/) to help facilitate both of these.

Using jQuery you can easily "bind" an event handler which will do something in response to a cell being clicked or hovered over.  For instance:

```
$('.des1').click(function() {
    // Whatever you put here will be triggered when the user clicks on an element
    // with class "des1"
});
```

The hover handler is similar, although slightly more complicated because it lets you specify both what happens when the user starts hovering and when they stop:

```
$('.des1').hover(function() {
    // Whatever you put here will be triggered when the user hovers over an element
    // with class "des1"
}, function() {
    // Whatever you put here will be triggered when the user stops hovering over an 
    // element with class "des1"
});
```

Inside the handlers you'll want to add logic to modify the text of the element with the appropriate ID, which you can do using jQuery's `text` method:

```
$('#des1').text('My Description #1');
```

Combining the two, and sharing a function between them, you get something like:

```
var showDescription1 = function() {
    // Whatever you put here will be triggered when the user clicks on an element
    // with class "des1"
};
$('.des1').click(showDescription1)
$('.des1').hover(showDescription1, function() {
     // if you want to change the description back when the user stops hovering, you'd
     // add that logic here
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks I go to learn Jquery in the next weeks when I have time for it, but for knknow I got it bymyself but ts not a really nice code i wrote.

Comment: Good luck: JQuery is one of the foundations of modern web development, so any time you spend learning it will be time well spent.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
    div.des {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="des1">Content 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="des2">Content 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="des3">Content 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="des1" class="des">Description 1</div>
<div id="des2" class="des">Description 2</div>
<div id="des3" class="des">Description 3</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('table td').on('click', function() {
        var $des = $('#' + $(this).attr('class')),
            visible = $des.hasClass('active');

        $('div').hide();

        if(visible) {
            return;
        }

        $des
            .addClass('active')
            .show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While code examples are certainly helpful, I think your answer would be more valuable if you could also provided further explanation of it, so that @guest can understand how to use that code.

Comment: thanks for the code too but machineghost comment is right. I always try to understand what I do and dont go with some finished code Piece.